# Color diff should be the default view on pending edit review pages

Tags: discussion, status-completed, suggested-edits, review, diff

The color diff should be the default view on pending edit review pages.

Comment: There's a color diff? I've totally been missing that :P

Comment: @Dave: Yeah, it's one of the buttons on the left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well yes it is now ... the rendered diff comes in technicolor.

The markdown side-by-side diff is also much improved.